# Bit shuffling to change encoding from little endian

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

So in the program I need to read an number from the user which needs to be changed from little endian encoding to whatever encoding the user wants to change it to. The encoding entered by the user is just a 4 digits number which just means which byte should be where after the encoding. e.g. 4321 means put the 4th byte first followed by the 3rd and so on. the encoding can take other form such as 3214 etc.

This is my code, would really appreciate if someone point out where I am missing out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 
class encoding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String byteOrder = sc.next();

        long[] bitMask = { // little endian
            Long.parseLong("11111111000000000000000000000000", 2),
            Long.parseLong("00000000111111110000000000000000", 2),
            Long.parseLong("00000000000000001111111100000000", 2),
            Long.parseLong("00000000000000000000000011111111", 2)
        };

        int[] bytes = {
            (int)(bitMask[0] & n),
            (int)(bitMask[1] & n),
            (int)(bitMask[2] & n),
            (int)(bitMask[3] & n)
        };

        int result = 0;
        shuffleBytes(bytes, byteOrder);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            bytes[i] = bytes[i] << (i * 8);
            result |= bytes[i];
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    static void shuffleBytes(int[] bytes, String encoding) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int index = Integer.parseInt(encoding.substring(i, i+1))-1;
            int copy = bytes[i];
            bytes[i] = bytes[index];
            bytes[index] = copy; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the problem you are experiencing to your question by [edit]ing. For instace, specify values for `n` and `byteOrder`, the result you got from that, and your expected result.

Comment: For strictly *reversing* there is also `Integer.reverseBytes` by the way

Answer (score 1):

## Fixing your current solution

There are two problems:

### 1. Forgot to right-align bytes

In ...

```
int[] bytes = {
    (int)(bitMask[0] & n),
    (int)(bitMask[1] & n),
    (int)(bitMask[2] & n),
    (int)(bitMask[3] & n)
};
```

... you forgot to shift each "byte" to the right. As a result, you end up with a list of "bytes" of the form `0x……000000, 0x00……0000, 0x0000……00, 0x000000……`. This is not a problem yet, but after `shuffleBytes` you shift each of these entries again using `bytes[i] = bytes[i] << (i * 8);`. As a result, the relevant parts (`__`) end up at a completely different spot or are shifted completely out of the integer.

To fix this, shift each `(int)(bitMask[…] & n)` to the right:

```
int[] bytes = {
    (int)(bitMask[0] & n) >> (3*8),
    (int)(bitMask[1] & n) >> (2*8),
    (int)(bitMask[2] & n) >> (1*8),
    (int)(bitMask[3] & n) >> (0*8)
};
```

### 2. Swapping more than once

In ...

```
static void shuffleBytes(int[] bytes, String encoding) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(encoding.substring(i, i+1))-1;
        int copy = bytes[i];
        bytes[i] = bytes[index];
        bytes[index] = copy; 
    }
}
```

... you swap some bytes multiple times because you operate in-place. To understand what happens consider the following minimal example where we want to swap two bytes using `order = "21"`. We inspect the variables before/after each iteration of the `for` loop.

0. The original input is `bytes = {x, y}` and `order = "21"`
1. We moved `bytes[0]` to `bytes[1]`. Now we have `bytes = {y, x}`.
2. But we are not finished yet. The loop continues and moves `bytes[1]` to `bytes[0]`. You assumed that `bytes[1]` would still be `y` at this point. However, because of the previous iteration this entry now holds `x` instead. Therefore, the result is `bytes = {x, y}`.

Here nothing changed, but for more entries you might also end up with something that is neither the original order nor the expected output order.

The easiest way to fix this is to write the result into a new array:

```
static int[] shuffleBytes(int[] bytes, String encoding) {
    int[] result = new int[bytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(encoding.substring(i, i+1))-1;
        result[index] = bytes[i]; 
    }
    return result; // also adapt main() to use this return value
}
```

## Alternative Solution

Even though you could fix your solution as described above I'm not too happy with it. Therefore, I propose this alternative solution which is cleaner, shorter, and more efficient.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Encoding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.format("input  = 0x%08x = %1$d%n", input);
        String newOrder = sc.next();
        int output = reorder(input, newOrder);
        System.out.format("output = 0x%08x = %1$d%n", output);
    }

    /** @param newOrder permutation of "1234" */
    static int reorder(int input, String newOrder) {
        int output = 0;
        for (char byte1Based : newOrder.toCharArray()) {
            output <<= 8;
            int shift = (byte1Based - '1') * 8;
            output |= ((0xFF << shift) & input) >> shift;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```